# testing a webservice locally

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl

i am trying to connect to a webservice from my local machine... i am using wamp as a local server and a wsdl connector provided by the webservice owners 
plus a php file to get the data and a XML testclient .exe file 
im trying to run the .exe file in cmd but this error occurs

```
Testclient started ...
upload URL: http://localhost/upload/php_server_2015-10-08/server.php
filename:   4485ae5f-4f9e-4ad6-bab3-44cdc57c09d5.xml
An error occured: The content type text/html of the response message does not 
match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a 
custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented 
properly. The first 1005 bytes of the response were: '<br />

<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' 
cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-
color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: 
Class 'SoapServer' not found in C:\wamp\www\upload\php_server_2015-10-
08\server.php on line <i>3</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left'    
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th 
align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' 
align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>874344</td><td 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td 
title='C:\wamp\www\upload\php_server_2015-10-08\server.php' 
bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\server.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
'.
Testclient done ... press key
```

can someone hekp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you get tells you `Class 'SoapServer' not found` which indicates that the Soap extension is not enabled.

Check your php.ini for the line `extension=php_soap.dll` and make sure it's not disabled (prefixed with a `;`).
If it is, remove the `;` in front of the line and restart Apache.

To locate your php.ini you should look in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.x.x\bin` (replace x accordingly ;) or just write a script containing

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Open this in your browser (http://localhost/.../yourscript.php) and look for "Loaded Configuration File".